# How to implement event manager of LibVLC using python

Tags: python, events, exception, libvlc

I'm successfully playing the video with LibVLC using python script, but i need to implement the event_ manager for identify & serve the player events.

I wrote code like follows:

```
import os
import sys
import vlc

from vlc import EventType

def video_end_reached():
    print "end_reached"
    player.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
filepath = "D:\\CHANDU_DATA\\ADAS_Automation\\LibVLC\\video_Python\\KUK_iPod.mp4"
movie = os.path.expanduser(filepath)
#if 'http://' not in filepath:
#if not os.access(movie, os.R_OK):
    #print ( 'Error: %s file is not readable' % movie )
    #sys.exit(1)
instance = vlc.Instance("--sout=#duplicate{dst=display{audio}}")
try:
   media = instance.media_new(movie)
except NameError:
   print ('NameError: % (%s vs Libvlc %s)' % (sys.exc_info()[1],
               vlc.__version__, vlc.libvlc_get_version()))
   sys.exit(1)

player = instance.media_player_new()
event_manager = player.event_manager()

player.set_media(media)

player.play()

event_manager.event_attach(EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, video_end_reached)

while():
   continue
```

But i'm trying to execute this code getting the error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\CHANDU_DATA\ADAS_Automation\LibVLC\video_Python\video.py", line 33, in <module>
event_manager.event_attach(EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, video_end_reached)
File "D:\CHANDU_DATA\ADAS_Automation\LibVLC\video_Python\vlc.py", line 1481, in event_attach
raise VLCException("%s required: %r" % ('argument', callback))
VLCException: argument required: <function video_end_reached at 0x02DAECF0>
```

please explain why this error is occurring & how to rectify it? can any one please mention how to implement event manager for LibVLC with python?

Comment: I found it & successfully implemented event manager for LibVLC using python script:

Comment: How did you get the event listener to fire?
I've having trouble with it.

event_m = m.event_manager()
event_m_p = p.event_manager()
#player
event_m_p.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerTitleChanged,callback)
#media
event_m.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaMetaChanged,callback)

i have a function called callback(e)  but nothing ever fires.
mind you I am playing a radio pls file.

Answer (score 2):

`video_end_reached` needs to take one argument for the event object.

```
def video_end_reached(event):
    print "end_reached"
    player.stop()
```

---

**Source:** https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/ (go to `EventManager` class and look at `event_attach`)

Answer (score 0):

i think u forgot to address the event manager for your player
before attaching event by `event_attach` method you should assign the event manager, which will receive and send event

```
my_event_manger = player.event_manager()
my_event_manger.event_attach(EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, video_end_reached)
```

i know this is old but for reference.